# Combine legend for several stat_function lines and raw data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")

data <- data.frame(c(0,1,2,3,4,5), c(-0.2, 0.6, 2.1, 3.8, 6.05, 7.6))
colnames(data) <- c("X", "Y")

f1 <- function(x)
{
    x - 0.2
}

f2 <- function(x)
{
    ifelse(x>=1.9,-2+x+0.1,0)
}

m <- function(x)
{
    f1(x) + f2(x)
}

graph <- ggplot(data, aes(X,Y, colour="Data")) + geom_point(stat = "identity") + xlim(c(0,5))
graph <- graph + scale_shape_discrete(name = "Data")

g1 <- stat_function(fun=f1, linetype="dashed", aes(colour="Function A"))
g2 <- stat_function(fun=f2, linetype="dashed", aes(colour="Function B"))
gm <- stat_function(fun=m,  aes(colour="Model"))

graph <- graph + g1 + g2 + gm
graph <- graph + scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red", "red", "red"))
print(graph)
```

That produces the following graph:

[image]

Where the legend does not really allow to distinguish between the various functions. I would rather expect a legend like:

[image]

Is it possible to produce something like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a (slightly ugly) possibility:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = "Data")) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = "Data"), alpha = 0) +
  stat_function(fun = f1, aes(colour = "Function A", linetype = "Function A")) +
  stat_function(fun = f2, aes(colour = "Function B", linetype = "Function B")) +
  stat_function(fun = m, aes(colour = "Model", linetype = "model")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("blank", "dashed", "dashed", "solid"),
                        guide = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red", "red", "red"),
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                        linetype = c("blank", "dashed", "dashed", "solid"),
                        size = c(2, 0, 0, 0)),
                        title = NULL))
```

[image]

I created a blank dummy line for the "Data" points (`geom_line` [...] `alpha = 0`); moved `linetype` to inside `aes`, removed `linetype` legend (`scale_linetype_manual` [...] `guide = FALSE`); changed  `linetype` and point `size` in the legend using `guide_legend(override.aes`.

Comment: Did not work for me; the resulting graph: http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b600/lads/Graph_zpse66550e7.png

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Strange that it doesn't work for you. Have you tried the basic stuff: latest version of R and `ggplot2`, and start with a clean R session?

Comment: Also please note that I made quite a few edits of my answer - make sure that you run the latest version (which apparantly works for me..;)

Comment: I am using R 3.1.1. The image posted above was generated with RStudio, however, trying it from Eclipse I got almost the same thing as you. I just had to tweak the line type for the "Data" series from `"dashed"` to `"blank"`. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I found out why RStudio and other programmes such as InkScape were not able to properly portrait the dashed lines. Their size was set to `0`, implying an invisible width. I corrected this in the answer.